# Unable to connect to the database - NEST.JS and TypeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm

So i have a problem with connecting to database in nest.js with typeorm and postgres. I have my local postgres instance running on docker. But when im running the app by yarn start it throws that error:

```
[Nest] 12736   - 2020-08-05 10:05:22   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +86ms 
QueryFailedError: no schematic representation of the creation of the object was indicated
```

My main app module

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(configService.getTypeOrmConfig()), UsersModule, LoginModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My config

```
  public getTypeOrmConfig(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: this.getValue('POSTGRES_HOST'),
      port: parseInt(this.getValue('POSTGRES_PORT')),
      username: this.getValue('POSTGRES_USER'),
      password: this.getValue('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
      database: this.getValue('POSTGRES_DATABASE'),
      entities: [__dirname + "/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
      synchronize: true,
    };
  }
```

My env file

```
POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kacluk123
POSTGRES_DATABASE=my_database
PORT=3000
MODE=DEV
```

Script to run docker/postgres

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

SERVER="my_database_server";
PW="kacluk123";
DB="my_database";

echo "echo stop & remove old docker [$SERVER] and starting new fresh instance of [$SERVER]"
(docker kill $SERVER || :) && \
  (docker rm $SERVER || :) && \
  docker run --name $SERVER -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$PW \
  -e PGPASSWORD=$PW \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -d postgres

# wait for pg to start
echo "sleep wait for pg-server [$SERVER] to start";
SLEEP 3;

# create the db 
echo "CREATE DATABASE $DB ENCODING 'UTF-8';" | docker exec -i $SERVER psql -U postgres
echo "\l" | docker exec -i $SERVER psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Have you mapped the postgres container port to your machines port ? ```docker run postgres -p 5432:5432```

Comment: Yes, i've updated post with docker script.

Comment: How do you get the instance of `configService` so that you can call `configService.getTypeOrmConfig`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I'ts a singleton initiated in other file.

Answer (score 1):

When I was facing this issue in my Nestjs and Typeorm project, my issue was my database wasn't actually created in my postgres, so I needed to create that. Note that my OS was Linux, I followed these steps for that.

- `sudo su - postgres`
- `psql` to enter into postgres cli commands
- `CREATE DATABASE databaseName;`

**Note the semicolon in the end of postgres command, these are mandatory in syntax**